# javascript regex to parse urls without protocol

Tags: javascript, regex, url, replace

```
String.prototype.linkify = function() {
this.replace(/((ht|f)tp:\/\/)?([^:\/\s]+)\w+.(com|net|org)/gi, '<a href="$&">$&</a>')
}
```

with `http://www.google.com http://yahoo.com www.facebook.com` it matches them all, however I want facebook to be prepended with the protocol group if it does not exist. Is there a way to do this without doing two `.replace` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
String.prototype.linkify = function () {
  return this.replace(/((?:ht|f)tp:\/\/)?([^:\/\s]+\w+\.(?:com|net|org))/gi, function (_, protocol, rest) {
    var url = (protocol || "http://") + rest
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>'
  })
}
```

(I fixed a couple of other problems with your code: you were missing a `return` and you were matching the domain name period using `.` rather than `\.`.)

And I assume I don’t need to point out how poorly this will match URL:s in general, due to a number of problems with your pattern.

Comment: :how would your regex go? also, can you explain the parameters in the anonymous function in replace?

Comment: The parameters are simply $&, $1, $2. My idea of a good way to match URLs in general is outside the scope of this question, since it is actually a pretty hard problem. To put it simply, though, I would start with a complete list of all TLDs, and then match stuff ending in a TLD and having various fluff on either side (that’s easier once you realize that you have to start from the TLD).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need to match FTP URLs, you can just assume the "http://" section of the link. This regex does that, while allowing you to also use https.

```
this.replace(/(http(s)?:\/\/)?(([^:\/\s]+)\.(com|net|org))/gi,
                         '<a href="http$2://$3">http$2://$3</a>')
```

I'm not sure what your use case is, but I'd like to note this regex will fail on the following urls:

- http://google.com/spam = <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>/spam
- http://google.ca = no match

This is because you're using few hardcoded tlds (com, net, org), and aren't matching any characters after the domain.

Comment: Clever solution to making sure to grab https as appropriate.